# Executing functions within switch dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have encountered a problem when putting all the modules I've developed into the main program. The switch dictionary I've created can be seen below:

```
def Tank_Shape_Calcs(Tank_Shape, level, area, dish, radius, length, Strapping_Table, Tank_Number):

    switcher = {
        0: vertical.Vertical_Tank(level, area),
        1: horiz.Horiz_Cylinder_Dished_Ends(dish, radius, level, length),
        2: strapping.Calc_Strapped_Volume(Strapping_Table, level),
        3: poly.Fifth_Poly_Calcs(Tank_Number)
    }
    return switcher.get(Tank_Shape, "ERROR: Tank type not valid")
```

The tank shape is set in the main file in a loop for each of the tanks. The first tank has `Tank_Shape = 2` so I would expect it to execute the `Calc_Strapped_Volume()` function.

I have tried testing it, and the switcher function is definitely reading `Tank_Shape` as `2`. Also if I change the functions to strings, it will print out the correct string.

The problem is that the functions seem to be executed sequentially, until the correct function is called. This results in errors as the data I'm using will only work with the correct function.

Is there a way to only execute the correct function?

Comment: The way you've structured your code (manually using a dictionary of lambdas for handling multiple behaviors, combining several different arguments that may or may not be needed depending on the desired behavior, &c.) suggests that you are new to Python. I would suggest you post a more complete copy of your code to codereview.stackexchange.com; some of the users there might be able to give you some tips on how to write your code more effectively :')

Answer (score 43, accepted):

All your functions are executed when you build the dictionary, not when you access the key.

You need to use `lambda` (without any parameters, they are already known) to make sure the function is only called when required:

```
switcher = {
    0: lambda : vertical.Vertical_Tank(level, area),
    1: lambda : horiz.Horiz_Cylinder_Dished_Ends(dish, radius, level, length),
    2: lambda : strapping.Calc_Strapped_Volume(Strapping_Table, level),
    3: lambda : poly.Fifth_Poly_Calcs(Tank_Number)
}
```

then call when you return, with the error message as a lambda that returns it:

```
return switcher.get(Tank_Shape, lambda : "ERROR: Tank type not valid")()
```

Comment: or _functools.partial_ instead of lambda

Comment: didn't know about `functools.partial`. Duly noted. (I hope to reuse it in a future answer :)) However, in that case `lambda` seems to be the best choice, since all args are passed, not only some..

Comment: Always happy to be of service :-) , _partial_ is excellent for callbacks. I myself sin with _lambda_ often enough, but - IMHO, in this case _partial_ looks a bit cleaner.  Matter of taste.

Comment: How the heck do you have 29k rep and a 999 score in Python and not know about `functools.partial`?

Comment: @jpmc26 I suppose you're teasing me in a friendly way. Well 29k doesn't come all from python of course. and I confess I don't know everything in Python. Martijn is that guy probably.

Comment: This was a very straight-forward way of fixing things, thanks. I have never used lambda before but this has opened my eyes to some of its potential uses.

Comment: About `functools.partial`: I'm a quick learner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715751/where-to-hold-common-strftime-strings-like-d-m-y/41715840#41715840 :)

Answer (score 18):

As noted, the functions will get invoked during dictionary construction. Besides that, there's two other issues I see here:

- Redefining `switcher` during every invocation of the function `Tank_Shape_Calcs`, this generally isn't a good idea.
- Requiring *all arguments to be passed* (due to their definition as positionals) when only a handful of them might be needed, this is why we have `*args` :-)

If my understanding of what you're up to is correct, I'd move switcher outside the function, as a `Tank_Shape` to `function` object mapping:

```
switcher = {
    0: vertical.Vertical_Tank,
    1: horiz.Horiz_Cylinder_Dished_Ends,
    2: strapping.Calc_Strapped_Volume,
    3: poly.Fifth_Poly_Calcs
}
```

Then, define `Tank_Shape_Calcs` to take the excess arguments as a tuple with `*args`:

```
def Tank_Shape_Calcs(Tank_Shape, *args):
    return switcher.get(Tank_Shape, lambda *_: "ERROR: Tank type not valid")(*args)
```

and invoke your function after `.get`ting it.

This also plays off Jean's trick to define a `lambda` in `.get` but does so with `*_` in order to allow it to get called with many args (which are consequently ignored).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm still looking over it fearing I missed something, the fact that no minimal example which I can test is given is feeding my insecurities.

Comment: I understand. At least the lambda thing is a safe enough modification. Let the OP test your solution. If it doesn't work, I'll withdraw my 4 upvotes :)

Comment: The problem, that I see, is that the single functions in the dictionary do not take all arguments from the outer function... as the result he will need to modify them, so they can handle all the arguments, even if they are not used in the particular function

Comment: Neat solution, but It seems a shame to use a `dict` when the keys are just like indexes, why not make `switcher` a `list`?

Comment: Dunno what the OP is exactly up to @Chris_Rands but a dict here allows for easy handling of the case where a key that doesn't exist via `.get`. You could do it with a list but it would arguably look clunkier. Also, a dictionary is intuitively more applicable here as a simulation of the switch statement .

Comment: Fair point, you could handle the absent case with a list too though like `l = [1,2]; l[5:6] or 'ERROR:'`

Comment: I am wondering what the benefit would be using this solution compared to the solution provided by @Jean-François Fabre? What is wrong with defining `switcher` every function call? Is it just because it's unneccesary or can it cause problems? As for using `*args`, I get an error saying `lambda takes no arguments (7 given)`. It is something I will have to look into more, but for now it is fine without `*args`. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Greenslade you probably didn't define `lambda` with `*_` hence the error. Redifining it won't lead to issues, it's just wasteful. Also, the fact that the function takes all `7` args when not all of them are needed is a suggestion that `*args` (which catch *any positionals passed*) should be used. Either way, it boils down to your preference just don't be confused if someone scratches their head over it :-)

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing in your code, is creating a dictionary with integer keys (0-3) and function results as values. Hence, you first call all the functions and then access the return values of these functions. I would change your code as following:

```
def Tank_Shape_Calcs(Tank_Shape, level, area, dish, radius, length, Strapping_Table, Tank_Number):
    switcher = {
        0: (vertical.Vertical_Tank, (level, area)),
        1: (horiz.Horiz_Cylinder_Dished_Ends, (dish, radius, level, length)),
        2: (strapping.Calc_Strapped_Volume, (Strapping_Table, level)),
        3: (poly.Fifth_Poly_Calcs, (Tank_Number,))
    }
    func, args = switcher.get(Tank_Shape, (None, None))
    if func is not None: 
        return func(*args)
```

Here, you get first the function you want to call with the according arguments and call it.

Comment: That's a good idea. You didn't emulate the error message, though, so if `Tank_Shape` is > 3 it crashes instead of returning a clear error string.

Comment: Is the comma after `Tank_Number` in case 3 correct?

Comment: @JDługosz, yes, otherwise you cannot define a tuple. You could alternatively define the arguments as lists, then the comma is not necessary.

Comment: Oh I see: my first reading, I supposed extra parens was like `&` and returned the function itself rather than calling it.