# Where to hold common strftime strings like ("%d/%m/%Y")

Tags: python, global-variables, strftime, format-string

In my app I find myself using **stftime** a lot, and mostly with 2 strings formats - ("%d/%m/%Y") and ("%H:%M")

Instead of writing the string each time, I want to store those strings in some global var or something, so I can define the format strings in just one place in my app.

What is the pythonic way of doing that? Should I use a global dict, a class, a function, or maybe something else?

Maybe like this?

```
class TimeFormats():
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = "%d/%m/%Y"
        self.time = "%H:%M"
```

Or like this?

```
def hourFormat(item):
    return item.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own settings module, like django does.

settings.py:

```
# locally customisable values go in here
DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"
TIME_FORMAT = "%H:%M"
# etc.
# note this is Python code, so it's possible to derive default values by 
# interrogating the external system, rather than just assigning names to constants.

# you can also define short helper functions in here, though some would
# insist that they should go in a separate my_utilities.py module.

# from moinuddin's answer

def datetime_to_str(datetime_obj):
    return datetime_obj.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
```

elsewhere

```
from settings import DATE_FORMAT
...
time.strftime( DATE_FORMAT, ...)
```

or

```
import settings
...
time.strftime( settings.DATE_FORMAT, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, using a settings file looks like a good central place to hold stuff like that

Answer (score 6):

you could use `functools.partial` to generate a function holding the format:

```
import time,functools

time_dhm = functools.partial(time.strftime,"%d/%m/%Y") 
time_hm = functools.partial(time.strftime,"%H:%M")

print(time_dhm(time.localtime()))
print(time_hm(time.localtime()))
```

result:

```
18/01/2017
10:38
```

you only have to pass the `time` structure to the new function. The function holds the format.

Note: you can do the same with `lambda`:

```
time_dhm = lambda t : time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y",t)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to create a custom function to achieve this. For example:

```
def datetime_to_str(datetime_obj):
    return datetime_obj.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Sample run:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime_to_str(datetime(1990, 3, 12))
'12/03/1990'
```

It will be much more friendly for the fellow developers as the function name is self explanatory. Each time conversion of `datetime` to `str` is needed, they will know which function is needed to be called. And in case you want to change the format through out the application; there will be single point of change.