# What does lambda do to stop switcher from executing all functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python, I used the the switcher dictionary. I encountered the problem of all the functions of the dictionary getting executed.

```
'''
Created on Mar 10, 2019

@author: priti

Questions 

1) Write a program that accepts a comma separated sequence of words as input and prints the words in a comma-separated sequence after sorting them alphabetically.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
without,hello,bag,world
Then, the output should be:
bag,hello,without,world

2) Write a program that accepts a sentence and calculate the number of upper case letters and lower case letters.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
Hello world!
Then, the output should be:
UPPER CASE 1
LOWER CASE 9

Hints:
In case of input data being supplied to the question, it should be assumed to be a console input.

3) (HINT use re i.e. import re (re is regular expression library/functions).
Question:
A website requires the users to input username and password to register. Write a program to check the validity of password input by users.
Following are the criteria for checking the password:
1. At least 1 letter between [a-z]
2. At least 1 number between [0-9]
1. At least 1 letter between [A-Z]
3. At least 1 character from [$#@]
4. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
5. Maximum length of transaction password: 12
Your program should accept a sequence of comma separated passwords and will check them according to the above criteria. Passwords that match the criteria are to be printed, each separated by a comma.
Example
If the following passwords are given as input to the program:
ABd1234@1,a F1#,2w3E*,2We3345
Then, the output of the program should be:
ABd1234@1
'''
# method used to perform operation regarding the first question
from unittest.util import sorted_list_difference
import re
def comma_separated():
    sorted_list=[]
    rawData = input("Please enter comma separated words\n")
    rawData = rawData.strip().split(",") 
    for item in rawData:
        item.strip()
        sorted_list.append(item)

    sorted_list.sort()


    for item in sorted_list:
        print(item)      

def cal_num_upper_lower():
    upperCase = 0
    lowerCase = 0
    rawData = input("Please enter string\n") 
    rawData.strip().split(",")   
    for i in rawData:
        #print(i)
        if(i.islower()):
            lowerCase +=1
        if(i.isupper()):
            upperCase +=1


    print("UPPER CASE = " + str(upperCase))
    print("LOWER CASE = " + str(lowerCase))                    
# method used to perform operation regarding the third question    
def check_regular_expression():
    sorted_list=[]

    password = input("Enter string to test: ")
    password = password.strip().split(",") 
    for item in password:
        item.strip()
        sorted_list.append(item)
#         
#             print("match")
    for item in sorted_list:
        if(re.match(r"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$]){6,12}", item)):
               print(item)

def choose_the_option(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        1: lambda: comma_separated(), 
        2: lambda: cal_num_upper_lower(), 
        3: lambda: check_regular_expression(), 
    }
    return switcher.get(argument,lambda: "Please enter a valid number") ()


print("Select one of the options")
option = int(input("1:Sort sequence of words\n2:Calculate Number of upper and lower case\n3:Check Regular Expression\n Please enter:"))
choose_the_option(option)
```

So I followed this question

> [Executing functions within switch dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698247/executing-functions-within-switch-dictionary)

Here is is mentioned that we need to use lambda to ensure only the correct method is called. While the solution worked perfectly,I could not get what exactly happens when we use lambda in switcher.
Thanks.

Comment: What you ask isn't clear enough, what do you want to understand ? why we put lambda in the switcher ? Also, i made an article on switch case if you want to take a look : https://sagecode.net/forum/programming/a-python-switch-case-essay/#post-78 (I'll add some more advanced versions really soon)

Comment: @Nenri thanks , yes I corrected the mistake and you are correct,I want to know that.

Comment: I don't know if you know what are lambda so i'll first explain you them.
Lambdas are anonym functions that you can put in a variable or a dict like there and that returns their content directly (so if you do for example `a = lambda: 2 + 3` and then `print(a())` it'll print 5).

You can add arguments to your lambda by doing `lambda args: code`.
Also note that putting your function call inside the lambda is overkill, u could just do
`0: func0` it'll work exactly same.

Comment: @Nenri If I use 0 : func() it will call all the methods while building the dictionary switcher.

Comment: so, remove the parenthesis, as i said `0: func`, the parenthesis make python execute the function but if you remove them, it'll just "store the function" (it doesn't exactly do that but store in fact a reference to the function)

Comment: okay thanks,will try and let you know.

Comment: Remember that you have to put parenthesis after, by doing `switcher[yourValue]()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190006/discussion-between-pritish-and-nenri).