# Making a dictionary of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a dictionary of lambda functions. It should be able to take a key and process whichever function is bound to that key and output the result.

```
func_dict = {
    "func1" : (z = lambda x, y: x + y),
    "func2" : (z = lambda x, y: x * y)
} # include benchmark functions

func = input("Choose a function: ")
output = func_dict[func](3, 5)
print(output)
```

That sample should print `8` but it doesn't run and simple gives me `can't assign to dictionary display` error on

```
    {
    "func1" : (z = lambda x, y: x + y),
    "func2" : (z = lambda x, y: x * y)
}
```

(indentation doesn't seem to be the problem)
I'd like to avoid using `eval()` & `exec()` if possible.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698247/executing-functions-within-switch-dictionary

Comment: You're probably gonna come across this as well, so be careful with `for` loops and `lambda`s. If you happen to generate your functions with a comprehension and end up with a strange behaviour, look for closures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your initial attempt is going to raise a syntax error.

Instead you would want to assign the definition of your lambda function directly to the key as follows

```
#The lambda function is assigned as a value of the keys
func_dict = {
    "func1" : lambda x, y: x + y,
    "func2" : lambda x, y: x * y
} 

func = input("Choose a function: ")
output = func_dict[func](3, 5)
print(output)
```

The output will be

```
Choose a function: func1
8

Choose a function: func2
15
```

Answer (score 5):

I think your assignment of `z =` is what's broken.

Try

```
func_dict = {
    "func1" : lambda x, y: x + y,
    "func2" : lambda x, y: x * y
} # include benchmark functions
```

Here's it working for me:

```
 ❯❯❯ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  3 2018, 11:24:55)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> func_dict = {
    "func1" : lambda x, y: x + y,
    "func2" : lambda x, y: x * y
} # include benchmark functions... ... ...
>>> func_dict["func1"](1,2)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is fine dude.

```
func_dict = {
    "func1" : lambda x, y: x + y,
    "func2" : lambda x, y: x * y
} # include benchmark functions

func = input("Choose a function: ")
output = func_dict[func](3, 5)
print(output)
```